# Javascript: effective array-based replacement in strings

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary, caching, replace

I am looking for a way to effectively (as in: with as little ressources as possible) replace orrurances of strings by other strings in Javascript. 
The focus is on computing time, more than memory consumption.

Search terms and replacements are given as a object used as dictionary

```
var replacements = {
    search    : 'replace',
    another   : 'replacement',
    'and one' : 'more'
}
```

Currently I'm iterating over the keys and building a regexp (with set g flag) out of them, then look up every match in the dictionary and replace it:

```
String.prototype.mapReplace = function (map, replaceFullOnly = false) {
    var regexp = [];
    for (var key in map) {
        regexp.push(RegExp.escape(key));
    }
    regexp = regexp.join('|');
    if (replaceFullOnly) {
        regexp = '\\b(?:' + regexp + ')\\b';
    }
    regexp = new RegExp(regexp, 'gi');
    return this.replace(regexp, function (match) {
        return map[match.toLowerCase()];
    });
}
```

This works, however I need to compile a new regular expresison every time. My question is: can somebody come up with an effective way to cache the regular expresisons and, if the same map (same as in "same keys", neither "same object" nor "same values" nor "same order of keys") is given again, the regular expresiosn is re-used?

One obvious way would be sorting, serializing and hashing keys, use it as a key to store the regular expresison and re-use stored regular expressions if existant on future calls. However, I tihnk this will most likely require more time than compiling a new regular expresiosn every time...

Ideas/input?

---

Edit: RegExp.escape() is a function that escapes special characters in strings for use in regular expressions:

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

---

Usage information:

- replacements are done a lot, as this i used in a chat system
- changes to the replacement map are infrequent, however it depends on how chat operators use the feature. Automated scripts adding and removing replacement rules automatically and frequently are possible. However, changes to the replacement map will always be less frequent than applying the replacement map to strings.
- one or multiple replacement maps might be in use simultaniously and independent of each other.

Comment: do you have some examples, what the mapreplace is doing?

Comment: Why not cache the compiled regexes explicitly? Just don't pass different map objects every time.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's used in a chat system where the operator can set new replacement rules dynamically. DIfferent rulesets for different users exist.

Comment: @Bergi Manually caching the regular expresison woudl require invalidating it whenever a replacement is added or removed. However this happens at multiple places throughout the application (as there is more than one way to add/remove pairs), so it is somewhat difficult to hold a reference to a cached regular expresison everywhere and update all of them when changes are made at one place.

Comment: @JohannesH. Are you saying you have a global `replacements` map that is updated from multiple places? Then just make that explicit, and encapsulate it in an object.

Comment: @JohannesH.: Since this is a performance question, we really need to know more about your usage characteristics. How often is one regex applied? How large are the strings? How often is the map updated (how many different maps are used)? And most of all: Have you actually implemented the naive version, measured its speed, and seen that it is too slow? Then please share your results.

Comment: @Bergi I have around 1 to 5 global replacements maps updated form multiple places, depending on how the feature is used.
The entire replacement is done a lot, as every chat message is parsed and one to all of the replacement maps used are run.
Changes happen infrequently, however I do not have data on it as I only write, not use the application.

Testing has not been done in production environment yet, my wish to improve performance is based solely on feedback by collegues. If you can come up with an accurate weay to measre performance, I'll gladly run tests.

Comment: @Bergi My next approach will most likely be to use a more specialized implementation for replacement maps that can store the regexp itself isntead of primitive objects. Invalidation can be handled within this ReplacementMap object(s) automatically.

Comment: Added usage information to the question

Comment: @JohannesH.: Yes, that approach is exactly what I meant with encapsulation. You can also add measuring code to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
var ReplacementMap = function (map, replaceFullOnly, ignoreCase) {

    var regexp = null;

    var update = function (search, replacement) {
        if (!isDefined(replacement)) {
            if (!(search in map)) return;
            delete map[search];
        } else {
            if (map[search] == replacement) return;
            map[search] = replacement;
        }
        invalidateRegexp();
    }

    var buildRegexp = function () {
        if (regexp != null) return;
        regexp = [];
        for (var key in map) {
            regexp.push(RegExp.escape(key));
        }
        regexp = regexp.join('|');
        if (replaceFullOnly) {
            regexp = '\\b(?:' + regexp + ')\\b';
        }
        regexp = new RegExp(regexp,'g' + (ignoreCase ? 'i' : ''));
    }

    var invalidateRegexp = function () {
        regexp = null;
    }

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        fullOnly : {
            set : value => {
                if (replaceFullOnly == value) return;
                replaceFullOnly = !!value;
                invalidateRegexp();
            },
            get : () => replaceFullOnly
        },
        ignoreCase : {
            set : value => {
                if (ignoreCase == value) return;
                ignoreCase = !!value;
                invalidateRegexp();
            },
            get : () => ignoreCase
        }
    });

    this.set = function set (search, replacement) {
        if (Array.isArray(search)) {
            if (Array.isArray(search[0])) {
                search.forEach(function (search) {
                    set(search);
                });
            } else {
                update(search[0], search.length > 1 ? search[1] : undefined);
            }
        } else if (search instanceof Object 
                && search !== null 
                && !String.isString(search)) {
            for (key in search) {
                update(key, search[key]);
            }
        } else update(search, replacement);
    }

    this.get = function (search) {
        return search in map ? map[search] : undefined;
    }

    this.remove = function(search) {
        update(search);
    }

    this.apply = function (string) {
        buildRegexp();
        return string.replace(regexp, function (match) {
            return map[match.toLowerCase()];
        });
    }

    this[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
        for (let key of Object.keys(map)) {
            yield {[key] : map[key]};
        }
        return;
    }

    if (isDefined(replaceFullOnly)) {
        replaceFullOnly = !!replaceFullOnly;
    } else {
        replaceFullOnly = true;
    }

    if (isDefined(ignoreCase)) {
        ignoreCase = !!ignoreCase;
    } else {
        ignoreCase = true;
    }

    if (isDefined(map)) {
        let entries = map;
        map = Object.create(null);
        this.set(entries);  
    } else {
        map = Object.create(null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// ---- CREATE MAP ----

// Empty Map
var m0 = new ReplacementMap(); 

// Map initialized with one replacement: foo => bar
var m1_1 = new ReplacementMap('foo','bar'); 
var m1_2 = new ReplacementMap(['foo','bar']); 
var m1_3 = new ReplacementMap({foo : 'bar'}); 

// Map initialized with two replacements: foo => bar, fooz => baz
var m2_1 = new ReplacementMap([['foo','bar'], ['fooz', 'baz']]); 
var m2_2 = new ReplacementMap({foo : 'bar', fooz : 'baz'}); 
var m2_3 = new ReplacementMap([{foo : 'bar'}, {fooz : 'baz'}]); 

// ---- ADD/MODIFY ENTRIES ----
var m0.set(...) // ... parameters work the same as in the constructor

// ---- REMOVE ENTRIES ----
var m2_1.delete('foo')  // removes replacement rule for foo => bar
var m2_1.delete('test') // fails silently

// ---- READ ENTRIES ----
var m2_1.get('foo')  // returns "bar"
var m2_1.get('test') // returns undefined;

for (rule of m2_1) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(rule));
}
// alerts "{'foo':'bar'}" and "{'fooz':'baz'}"


// ---- APPLY ON STRING ----
alert(m2_1.apply("foo bar")) // bar bar

// change behaviour:
m2_1.fullOnly = true;   // replace foo with bar, but not foobar with barbar
                        // default: true;

m2_1.ignoreCase = true; // ignore case. default: true
```